# For loop format in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am wondering how is this program executed at all and does not throw any error.

```
void main( ) 
{ 
    clrscr();
    int i ; 
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%c", 65 ) ) ; 
        i++ ;
    getch(); 
}
```

The loop goes on printing A forever. The format of for loop is

```
for(initialize value; test counter; increment value)
{
    do this;
    and this;
    and this;
}
```

My question is how can printf("\n %c", 65) increment the value?

Comment: `i++` is unreachable.

Comment: `printf` on success returns the total number of characters written. Its not incrementing `i`

Comment: who gave you this tricky code?

Comment: And why to complicate your life? After removing the `;`, put the `i++` where it should be. Don't do weird things, no one will love you.

Comment: semicolon is treated as the body of the loop.According to `(C99, 6.8.3p3) "A null statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no operations."`

Answer (score 15):

The trailing `;` after the [`for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for) results in `i` not being incremented inside the `for`, causing an infinite loop.

This:

```
for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%c", 65 ) ) ; 
    i++ ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%c", 65 ) ) {} /* Empty loop body. */
i++ ;
```

The `i++` is never reached. To correct, remove the trailing `;`. It would be clearer to use the `i++` as the iteration expression in the `for` loop and not the `printf()` and `i` does not need to exist outside of the loop body:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    printf ( "\n%c", 65 );
}
```

---

> My question is how can `printf("\n %c", 65)` increment the value?

[`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) returns the number of characters written so it would be possible to use it to increment `i` if you wish but it would be neccessary to change the terminating condition to account for `\n` character:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i+= printf("\n%c", 65));
```

However, this is less clear than the previous suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%c", 65 ) ) ;` is in itself a statement `i` is not incremented in this statement and so infinite loop.

This is called a blank loop: it is similar to empty for loop.

Without infinite loop

```
for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%c", 65 ) ){
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have self given the format for `for loop` is

```
for(initialize value; test counter; increment value)
{
    do this;
    and this;
    and this;
}
```

but you have used

```
for(initialize value; test counter; increment value);
{
   do this;
   and this;
   and this;
}
```

Placing `;` after `for()` will result in executing null statement. And this will not allow the program to increment `i`---resulting in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

just write

```
void main( ) 
{ 
    clrscr();
    int i ; 
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%c", 65 ) ) 
        i++ ;
    getch(); 
}
```

and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

```
for(initialize value; condition; increment value/decrement value)
{
    do this;
    and this;
    and this;
}
you can write many initializations, many increments/decrements but we have to write only one condition
```

i.e( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%c", 65),i++ ); this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because, as said above, i++ is unreachable, since ";" after a for statement equals to a for with a blank body.

You could have written this loop as follows:

```
for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%c", 65 ) , i++);
```

for obtaining the same effect and without writing an explicit block.